# Unable to resize lvm to max of vda

Tags: lvm, virsh

I am trying to resize my lvm partition frm 29GB to ~60GB. Here is my current status:

```
root@demo:~# lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0    99M  1 loop /snap/core/11081
loop1                       7:1    0  99.2M  1 loop /snap/core/11167
loop2                       7:2    0  55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2066
loop3                       7:3    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/1997
loop4                       7:4    0 125.9M  1 loop /snap/docker/471
loop5                       7:5    0 131.6M  1 loop /snap/docker/796
loop6                       7:6    0  70.4M  1 loop /snap/lxd/19647
loop7                       7:7    0  32.1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12057
loop8                       7:8    0  32.1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11841
loop9                       7:9    0  67.6M  1 loop /snap/lxd/20326
sr0                        11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
vda                       252:0    0    60G  0 disk 
├─vda1                    252:1    0     1M  0 part 
├─vda2                    252:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─vda3                    252:3    0    59G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0    29G  0 lvm  /
```

As you can observe, my vda3 is 59G and my lvm is 29G. When I run the following commands I am unable to resize the lvm to ~59G.

```
root@demo:~# lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
  New size (7423 extents) matches existing size (7423 extents).
root@demo:~# resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
The filesystem is already 7601152 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!

root@demo:~#
```

How can I fix it?

Later edits:

```
root@demo:~# vgs
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  ubuntu-vg   1   1   0 wz--n- <29.00g    0
```

Comment: What is the size of the volume group (`vgs`)?

Comment: @eblock   ubuntu-vg   1   1   0 wz--n- <29.00g    0

Comment: Then you need to extend the volume group first.

Comment: @eblock `pvresize /dev/vda3` did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Apprently it worked with:

```
root@demo:~# lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0    99M  1 loop /snap/core/11081
loop1                       7:1    0  99.2M  1 loop /snap/core/11167
loop2                       7:2    0  55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2066
loop3                       7:3    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/1997
loop4                       7:4    0 125.9M  1 loop /snap/docker/471
loop5                       7:5    0 131.6M  1 loop /snap/docker/796
loop6                       7:6    0  70.4M  1 loop /snap/lxd/19647
loop7                       7:7    0  32.1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12057
loop8                       7:8    0  32.1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11841
loop9                       7:9    0  67.6M  1 loop /snap/lxd/20326
sr0                        11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
vda                       252:0    0    60G  0 disk 
├─vda1                    252:1    0     1M  0 part 
├─vda2                    252:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─vda3                    252:3    0    59G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0    29G  0 lvm  /
root@demo:~# pvresize /dev/vda3
  Physical volume "/dev/vda3" changed
  1 physical volume(s) resized or updated / 0 physical volume(s) not resized
root@demo:~# vgs
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree 
  ubuntu-vg   1   1   0 wz--n- <59.00g 30.00g
root@demo:~# lvextend -r -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```